# How to get Tweets of a Keyword

Tags: python, twitter, streaming, tweepy

I'm trying to get tweets from a certain keyword 'comfama'. but I can't seem to get any results. Is something wrong with my code? I'm tried with 'donald trump' and this keyword shows results but with 'comfama' nothing happens.

```
import tweepy
import pandas
import json # The API returns JSON formatted text

TRACKING_KEYWORDS = ['comfama']
OUTPUT_FILE = "comfama_tweets.txt"
TWEETS_TO_CAPTURE = 10


access_token = "xxx"
access_token_secret = "xxx"
consumer_key = "xxx"
consumer_secret = "xxx"

# Pass OAuth details to tweepy's OAuth handler
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    """
    Twitter listener, collects streaming tweets and output to a file
    """
    def __init__(self, api=None):
        super(MyStreamListener, self).__init__()
        self.num_tweets = 0
        self.file = open(OUTPUT_FILE, "w")

    def on_status(self, status):
        tweet = status._json
        self.file.write( json.dumps(tweet) + '\n' )
        self.num_tweets += 1
        
        # Stops streaming when it reaches the limit
        if self.num_tweets <= TWEETS_TO_CAPTURE:
            if self.num_tweets % 100 == 0: # just to see some progress...
                print('Numer of tweets captured so far: {}'.format(self.num_tweets))
            return True
        else:
            return False
        self.file.close()

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)


# Initialize Stream listener
l = MyStreamListener()

# Create you Stream object with authentication
stream = tweepy.Stream(auth, l)

# Filter Twitter Streams to capture data by the keywords:
stream.filter(track=[TRACKING_KEYWORDS])
```